# AWS EC2 - ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, memory, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instances with 16 GB ram, but why I'm getting this error

````
pip install tensorflow==1.12.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tensorflow==1.12.0
  Using cached tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (83.1 MB)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device```

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.7G  7.5G  186M  98% /
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  796K  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop3       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop1       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop4       69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/14804
/dev/loop6       72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/15564
/dev/loop5       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000


free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16011         192       15131           1         687       15530
Swap:             0           0           0
````

Comment: RAM is not for storage - also note that `/dev/root       7.7G  7.5G  186M  98% /`, there are only 186 MB left on your `/` - the tensorflow wheel after extraction is going to exceed that space.

Comment: @metatoaster can you suggest me what should I do now

Comment: @RahulVerma See this page to learn how to expand the root EBS volume: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/